# It is possible to have two devices with the same UUID?

Tags: cordova, authentication, uuid

I am PhoneGap developer and my app is for android Windows and iOS. I used UUID as the username in the application.

Is it possible to have two devices with the same UUID?

Is UUID unique over the world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is almost impossible to get a collision in UUID.

From Wikipedia:

> Randomly generated UUIDs have 122 random bits. Out of a total of 128
> bits, four bits are used for the version ('Randomly generated UUID'),
> and two bits for the variant ('Leach-Salz').
>
> With random UUIDs, the
> chance of two having the same value can be calculated using
> probability theory (Birthday paradox). Using the approximation
>
> `p(n)\approx 1-e^{-\tfrac{n^2}{{2x}}}`
>
> these are the probabilities of an
> accidental clash after calculating n UUIDs, with x=2122:
>
> n probability
> 68,719,476,736 = 236  0.0000000000000004 (4 × 10−16)
> 2,199,023,255,552 = 241   0.0000000000004 (4 × 10−13)
> 70,368,744,177,664 = 246  0.0000000004 (4 × 10−10)
>
> To put these numbers into perspective,
> the annual risk of someone being hit by a meteorite is estimated to be
> one chance in 17 billion, which means the probability is about
> 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11), equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of > UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate. In
> other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for
> the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate
> would be about 50%. The probability of one duplicate would be about
> 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.

Answer (score -2):

UUID means Universally Unique Identifier.
It must be unique for all the devices.
You never get the same UUID from the android, windows or iOS devices.

Is it possible to have two devices with the same UUID?

> Its not possible.

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible but the probability is really really small...